# How is conflicting asset filename created

Tags: assets, controller

I upload files on the frontend using AJAX requests to `actionUpload` controller. When file is uploaded, I immediately display it using filename returned by controller.

In case if filename conflict, the duplicate file is created, with a name like `something_200518_221543.jpg`. How can I retrieve this duplicate filename, so I can display this file too? In control panel, this duplicate filename is somehow appended to the page, but I don't know how - there is no request that returns this new filename from backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be possible as of the next Craft release, which will be 3.4.21: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/commit/a787fe0ef37841706a5a9910fbeae0391da3be6f